# Question about an error for unexpected else statement

Tags: php

I can not seem to find the error as I am not too familiar with all this but I am trying to learn. What my issue is, I have an if statement that has multiple else statements in it. When I go onto my website, it says "syntax error, unexpected 'else' in ... on line 20. Below is the page content.

```
<?php

    $info = (Object)[];
    $data = false;

    $data['email'] = $DATA_OBJ->email;

    if($Error == "") {
        $query = "select * from users where email = :email limit 1";
        $result = $DB->read($query, $data);

        if(is_array($result)) {
            $result = $result[0];
            if($result->password == $DATA_OBJ->password) {
                
            } else {
                $info->message = "Wrong password! Please try again.";
                $info->data_type = "error";
                echo json_encode($info);
            } else {
                $info->message = "Incorrect email. Please try again!";
                $info->data_type = "error";
                echo json_encode($info);
            } else {
                $info->message = $Error;
                $info->data_type = "error";
                echo json_encode($info);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't use multiple `else` in a `if else` condition, you should change it to `else if`

Comment: @MustafaPoya how would you recommend that I do that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @justRyan I commited an answer for you, please check it.

Comment: if($condition) {  } else if($condition)  else if($condition) { }else{}

Comment: **Warning:** Don't expose if it was the email or password that was wrong. Just return a generic error, something like: "Invalid credentials". If not, people can use the log in as a look up for knowing what users have registered or not, based on the email, narrowing things down for potential hackers. So you should stick to one `if` (where both email and pass are correct) with one `else` (if either is incorrect).

Comment: **Warning:** This: `$result->password == $DATA_OBJ->password` indicates that you're not properly hashing your passwords. You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash. **Never** store passwords in plain text and don't try and roll your own hashing algorithm.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there any way I can message you? Discord, Email, etc. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. I have done what people have suggested and it still isn't working. I need a better understanding of this.

Comment: [Here's a post about password hashing](https://docs.php.earth/security/passwords/) with detailed explanation on how and why it's critical that you do it. [Here is a post that explains the invalid credentials issue](https://tarunbatra.com/blog/security/Error-messages-in-login-process-Privacy-and-Security/) and why it's important to not show too much detail.

Comment: Regarding the `if/else` issue, there are much info in the manual. About `if`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php and about `else`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php and about `elseif`: https://www.php.net/control-structures.elseif

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($result)) {
    $result = $result[0];
    if($result->password == $DATA_OBJ->password) {
        
    } else if(/* condition for wrong password*/) {
        $info->message = "Wrong password! Please try again.";
        $info->data_type = "error";
        echo json_encode($info);
    } else if(/* condition for wrong email */){
        $info->message = "Incorrect email. Please try again!";
        $info->data_type = "error";
        echo json_encode($info);
    } else {
        $info->message = $Error;
        $info->data_type = "error";
        echo json_encode($info);
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, I should say ?

} else if ("password != "password") { 
$info->message = "Wrong password! Please try again.";
$info->data_type = "error";
echo json_encode($info); 
}

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help. I know I sounded like a noob but hey we all start somewhere.

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you outside of StockOverflow? I am still having an issue and would like if you were able to help me further.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 1 `else` statement per `if` statement. In your code the inner `if` has 3 `else` statements. I guess what you want is to put the other `else` statements under the other `if` statements like this:

```php
if($Error == "") {
    $query = "select * from users where email = :email limit 1";
    $result = $DB->read($query, $data);

    if(is_array($result)) {
        $result = $result[0];
        if($result->password == $DATA_OBJ->password) {
              
        } else {
            $info->message = "Wrong password! Please try again.";
            $info->data_type = "error";
            echo json_encode($info);
        }
    } else {
        $info->message = "Incorrect email. Please try again!";
        $info->data_type = "error";
        echo json_encode($info);
    } 
} else {
    $info->message = $Error;
    $info->data_type = "error";
    echo json_encode($info);
}
```